# How do I center a div with max-width in flex.flex-col container (TailwindCSS)

Tags: flexbox, tailwind-css

I have this

```html
<div class="flex flex-col">
  <main class="max-w-screen-lg mx-auto">...</main>
  ...
</div>
```

I use mx-auto to center main
I also want main to have some maximal width on large screen that's why I use max-w-screen-lg!

But in result margin left and right takes all space around and shrinks main to its minimal possible width on large screen

I just want main to have max width centered inside container

Some possible solution might be this, but it requires extra div

```html
<div class="flex flex-col">
  <div>
    <main class="max-w-screen-lg mx-auto">...</main>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `w-full` should make it work.

```html
<div class="flex flex-col">
  <main class="w-full max-w-screen-lg mx-auto">...</main>
  ...
</div>
```